# Saving two records in Rails at the same time where one has a foreign_key pointing to the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Pool
  has_many :memberships
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :pool, presence: true
end
```

This is the association I have. Whenever a new pool is created, I also want to create an entry into the membership class.

```
class Api::PoolsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @pool = Pool.new(pool_params)
    member = Membership.new(user_id: current_user.id, pool_id: @pool.id)
    ...
  end
end
```

The issue is that `@pool` is not currently saved to the database yet, so it does not have an `id` value.

Is there a way that I can tell `member` to add the id after `@pool` is saved? Basically linking them to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Api::PoolsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @pool = Pool.new(pool_params)
    member = @pool.memberships.new(user_id: current_user.id)
    ...
  end
end
```